# What's going on with this question?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/587/40) (edit: as well as [this](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/631/40)) is downvoted which brought me here. I've observed the following phenomenon:

1. Lots of users are asking questions about 'what should be a syntax for x'. The fact is, as long as the syntax is parseable, whatever can be chosen as a syntax for whatever thing (see [this](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/579/40), [this](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/570/40), etc.).
   For example, a lambda syntax can be `this-is-a-lambda-look-at-me-i-am-cool x: x` or `((((((((x))))))) => x` (maybe because they like [this joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/7sk1rx/a_spy_manages_to_steal_the_last_50mb_of_the_lisp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)), but it's up to opinion which one is *good*. How should we vote & downvote & accept these kinds of answers? Why are these questions so upvoted?
2. People seem to dislike questions that are commonsensical, but different people have different definitions of commonsense. For example, [this](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/33/40) (what's bad about layout syntax) is well-accepted, while [this](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/587/40) (pros-and-cons of static typinh) is downvoted. To me, both seem elementary school level programming questions, but I can't say for everyone.

The current state of this site is exactly as described in [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32850/216761) on the proposal: most questions are opinion-based, the rest are mostly listing ideas & facts, then there are a few questions on semantics & edge cases of syntaxes.

How should we deal with this? Should we make a standard for questions being acceptable or not?

Comment: There's only one downvote currently; were there more previously?

Comment: @MichaelHomer there were two when the question is out, then I commented, then there became only one. Seems like I put some pressure on people

Comment: Personally, I do think a lot of the pros-cons questions are not great, and this one could definitely try to be a better and question.

Comment: What baffles me is that the close vote is for "Needs more focus". Really??

Comment: How are “most” questions option based? I don’t see that many, if any

Comment: @Seggan just look up the tag `syntax`: https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax I see about 5-10 informative questions, and the rest are opinion based.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I am very upset by this. It reached a score of -3 at one point with no explanation and 2 close votes for needs more focus. This is nonsense and we have discussed that these questions are fine. The make up the majority of our questions. I upvoted it simply for this reason. We have a standard. This just seems like people expressing that they dont like those types of questions. This isnt meta though, thats not what upvote/downvotes are for.

Comment: Your question was closed because it failed to meet the referencing requirements, not because it was some wrong type of question

Comment: Nothing to do with my question

Comment: Mass downvoting no explaination

Comment: Because they disagree?

Comment: Okay then but why. @Seggan

Comment: I already said why. Because they disagree. I personally downvoted because the last sentence does not necessarily apply during private beta, were we *need* to quickly define what kind of questions we want and don't want. Additionally, upvoting just because everyone else is downvoting doesnt makse sense.

Comment: This isn't meta, why do you disagree with that. I am upvoting because of basically serial downvoting (vote on the post not your opinion of questions weve decided are fine) @Seggan

Comment: This *is* meta tho

Comment: Downvoting my post bc you disagree is fine but downvoting the post the question is talking about bc you disagree with a decision is not @Seggan

Comment: I never said that I downvoted the main post. Also, the decision you cite (where is it anyway?) was only a few days old at the time, that isnt enough time to solidify a decision.

Comment: Um... in the private beta it kind of is enough to call it a decisiion or else well have no decisions to base anything off @Seggan

Comment: Conversely, in private beta decisions may be overturned much more quickly, and so are in flux constantly.

Comment: True but until said overturning they are in effect @Seggan

Comment: The downvotes are people showing dissatisfaction with the decision; is it not part of helping overturn it?

Comment: This is not the decision post @Seggan

Comment: Now I'm speaking of the downvotes on the main post

Comment: But the question is why only votes on the one post @Seggan for the future clarifiy which post i am also talking about the main post